# d3 circle pack layout for bubble chart - how can I enable bubble dragging in pack layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag, circle-pack

I am using d3.layout.pack for rendering bubble chart. 
Code is here : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530

Chart renders properly, now I want to make the inner bubbles draggable. so user can move the circles inside the main outer circle.

I did same with help of force layout but not able to do it with pack layout.